# WP-REST create user with custom meta

Tags: rest-api

Hello first time messing with wordpress. I'm trying to create users from another express app but having some problem creating custom meta for them ? 
I tried a POST like this but it failed to create my custom key messenger id in the usersmeta

```
{
    "username" : "test2",
    "email": "test2@gmail.com",
    "password": "123456",
    "meta": {
        "messengerId": "11223344"
    }

}
```